# How to create a new Tkinter window frame within a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I am making a GUI with Tkinter. I also want to make a frame within the Tkinter window, and it should open when I click a button.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

screen = Tk()
screen.title("My GUI")
screen.geometry("600x600")
screen.configure(background="Gray")

button1 = Button(screen)
button.pack()

screen.mainloop
```

So how do I make a new window(frame) when I click the button?

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a function that creates the frame, and calling it from the button?

Comment: Define a callback function that does what you want, and arrange for it to be called when the `Button` is clicked by using something like `button1 = Button(screen, command=my_callback_function)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "frame within the Tkinter Window"?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to create a frame, and there aren't any good tutorials that help. So I asked here.

Comment: You create a frame pretty much exactly like you create a button (except for the name, of course). `the_frame= Frame(screen)`.

Comment: Thank you Bryan Oakley, so after creating a frame, how do I use it. When I click on a button it should change the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create/toggle frame following the below logic

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

screen = Tk()
screen.title("My GUI")
screen.geometry("600x600")
screen.configure(background="Gray")

frame_enabled = False


def toggle_frame():
    global frame_enabled
    if not frame_enabled:
        my_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    else:
        my_frame.pack_forget()
    frame_enabled = not frame_enabled


button1 = Button(screen, text="Toggle frame", command=toggle_frame)
button1.pack()

my_frame = Frame(screen, bg="red")
screen.mainloop()
```